# Complex derivatives of non-holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

I am having problems reconciling two results that seem to be at odds with each other.

On the one hand, I find [references](https://dantaylor688.github.io/2018/01/08/complex-polynomial/) to the fact that $$\partial_z \mathrm{Re}(f(z)) = \mathrm{Re}(\partial_zf(z))$$ and therefore $$\partial_z\mathrm{Re(z)} = 1$$
On the other hand, $$\mathrm{Re}(z) = \frac{z+z^*}{2}$$ and so $$\partial_z \frac{z+z^*}{2}= \frac12$$ The caveat is that in the second case I'm treating $z$ and $z^*$ as independent variables, which I understand is the correct thing to do when we derive non-holomorphic functions.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: I just realized that in the reference the derivative is with respect to a real variable...

Comment: In order for the complex partial $\partial_z$ to line up with our intuition for how to take derivatives the usual way, it is defined with a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ with the real partials. So the faulty line of reasoning would be the first one. $\partial_z \operatorname{Re} (z)$ would really be $\frac{1}{2}$ because of this factor i.e. $$\partial_z = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_x - i\partial_y) \implies \partial_z (x) = \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Okay, so you confirm that the correct result is indeed $\frac12$. Then there must be something wrong in Tensorflow and Jax, because I have just checked and both return a derivative of 1...

Comment: They're not necessarily wrong, the factor is a convention, and both conventions with or without it pop up here and again. However, if you don't use the $\frac{1}{2}$, you cannot use your normal derivative rules to calculate the derivative heuristically with just $z$'s and that is the main advantage of this convention.

Comment: To illustrate this example, if the convention was factorless, then the second line of reasoning would be incorrect. $\partial_z \left(\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2}\right)$ would be $1$ because of the lack of factor or just from definition: $$(\partial_x - i\partial_y)(x) = 1$$